# Error uploading file to SharePoint using .NET Framework 4.5

Tags: sharepoint-online, client-object-model, console-application

I have a problem uploading files to SharePoint from a .NET console application. I get the error  "Cannot write data to transport connection: An existing connection has been forced to break by the remote host".

in ExecuteQuery generate exception

my code

#region ConnectToSharePoint

```
        var securePassword = new SecureString();
        foreach (char c in Password)
        { securePassword.AppendChar(c); }
        var onlineCredentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(Login, securePassword);
        #endregion
        #region Insert the data
        using (ClientContext CContext = new ClientContext(SiteUrl))
        {
            CContext.Credentials = onlineCredentials;
            Web web = CContext.Web;
            FileCreationInformation newFile = new FileCreationInformation();
            byte[] FileContent = FileName.Arreglo;
            newFile.ContentStream = new MemoryStream(FileContent);
            newFile.Url = FileName.Nombre;
            List DocumentLibrary = web.Lists.GetByTitle(DocLibrary);
            //SP.Folder folder = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.GetByUrl(ClientSubFolder);
            Folder Clientfolder = DocumentLibrary.RootFolder.Folders.Add(ClientSubFolder);
            Clientfolder.Update();
            File uploadFile = Clientfolder.Files.Add(newFile);

            CContext.Load(DocumentLibrary);
            CContext.Load(uploadFile);
            CContext.ExecuteQuery();
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("The File has been uploaded" + Environment.NewLine + "FileUrl -->" + SiteUrl + "/" + DocLibrary + "/" + ClientSubFolder + "/" + FileName.Nombre);
        }
        #endregion
    }
    catch (Exception exp)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red;
        Console.WriteLine(exp.Message + Environment.NewLine + exp.StackTrace);
    }
    finally
    {
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Please someone help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.NET Framework 4.5 uses TLS 1.0 by default. Microsoft does not allow TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1 clients to connect to SharePoint Online. Add the following line of code before you create the `ClientContext` to tell .NET to use TLS 1.2. This should correct the issue.

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`